# Is it possible to increase the Maximum number of simultaneous CFC function requests on ColdFusion 10 Standard?

Tags: coldfusion

We build a REST API on a Coldfusion 10 Standard Instance.  However, load tests have shown massive failure.

We have narrowed it down to ColdFusion and assume it is limiting the number of simultaneous requests.

Can this be adjusted in any way in CF Standard 10?

Answer (score 1):

In the Admin under "request Tuning" you will find a max number of simultaneous requests. 4 to 6 times your number of cores is a good rule of thumb.

Also, if you are using IIS the maxworkerthreads can serve as a separate limit on the number of requests you are able to process. Here's a blog post that might be of use - [maxworker threads](http://www.coldfusionmuse.com/index.cfm/2011/11/5/maxworkerthreads.bug).

Let us know if you need more *formal* (ie paid consulting) help. :)